Extracting Traffic Data from 3proxy Counter Logs Using PHP
I have a 3proxy server where I enabled traffic counters for configurations. In the .cfg file, I use the following lines to activate the counter:
# Count traffic
counter "<logfile/>"
countin 1 M 200000 * * *
countout 1 M 200000 * * *

On the server, there is a config directory containing multiple .cfg files. Each configuration has its own folder named after the configuration, and within that folder, the corresponding counter .log file is stored.
I need to parse the counter log files using PHP to extract incoming and outgoing traffic. Despite testing multiple approaches, the results seem inaccurate due to issues with hex parsing.
Example Scenario
For a specific configuration, I installed the proxy in a browser and ran a speed test on Fast.com. The test results showed:
450 MB download
300 MB upload

Here’s the hexdump of the corresponding log file:
hexdump -C /config/test1/test1.log | head
00000000  33 43 46 00 00 00 00 00  8c e5 44 67 00 00 00 00  |3CF.......Dg....|
00000010  fa d4 ca 11 00 00 00 00  3c a2 43 67 00 00 00 00  |........<.Cg....|
00000020  b2 e2 44 67 00 00 00 00                           |..Dg....|
00000028

Using my PHP script, the extracted traffic is as follows:
Incoming: 284.68 MB (somewhat accurate)
Outgoing: 1.61 GB (incorrect and identical across all configurations)
How should I correctly parse incoming and outgoing traffic from 3proxy counter logs using PHP?
Here is my current script:
https://github.com/user-attachments/files/17909026/3proxy-traffic-counter.txt
Thanks!
